# Unable to add css animation property to component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I am passing a function to a material UI component that should be injecting a background animation. The ternary is working correctly as I am able to inject basic CSS styles like `{ backgroundColor: "#3b69f2" }` . Any help finding what I have done wrong with the keyframes / animation code would be massively appreciated!

**Component**

```
<TableRow style={{ ...styleRowHiglight, ...styleActionable, ...styleRowActionHighlight }}>
```

**Function**

```
const styleRowActionHighlight = getter('matter', 'records', 'highlightRow') 
 ===recordConfig['meta']['id'] ?

{
  "@keyframes bgcolorchange": {
     "99.9%": { backgroundColor: "blue" },
     "100%": { backgroundColor: "blue" }
   },
   "@-webkit-keyframes bgcolorchange": {
     "99.9%": { backgroundColor: "blue" },
     "100%": { backgroundColor: "blue" }
   },
   "@-moz-keyframes bgcolorchange": {
     "99.9%": { backgroundColor: "blue" },
     "100%": { backgroundColor: "blue" }
   },
   "@-o-keyframes bgcolorchange": {
     "99.9%": { backgroundColor: "blue" },
     "100%": { backgroundColor: "blue" }
   },
   WebkitAnimation: "bgcolorchange 5s infinite",
   MozAnimation: "bgcolorchange 5s infinite",
   OAnimation: "bgcolorchange 5s infinite",
   animation: "bgcolorchange 5s infinite",
   } 
   :
   {};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are pointing towards the animation name. try using $ sign before the keyframe name like below code

```
WebkitAnimation: "$bgcolorchange 5s infinite",
MozAnimation: "$bgcolorchange 5s infinite",
OAnimation: "$bgcolorchange 5s infinite",
animation: "$bgcolorchange 5s infinite",
```